# Creating Header/Banner that users can customise

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a feature header generator that gives users the ability to customise it with colours, images and text? Then save it and add it to their website?

[I have created a feature banner demo here to give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve](http://jsfiddle.net/94jf2/1/). (Source code is at the bottom of this post)

I want users to be able to:

- Change the colour of the gradient from a predefined dropdown list
- Insert their own text (shown on top of the gradient
- Add their own image to the right div

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Many thanks,

Ross

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         body {
         font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
         font-weight: 300;
         }
         img {
         display: block;
         }
         h3 {
         font-size:200%
         }
          #container {
         width: 100%;
         height: 150px;
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:1px;
         border-color:#a9a9a9;
         }
         #container > div {
         display: table-cell;
         }
         #left {
         width: 250px;
         vertical-align: middle;
         }
         #middle {
         width: 80%;
         min-width: 400px;
         max-width: 960px;
         color:white;
         text-align:center;
         vertical-align:middle;
         /* fallback */
         background-color: #9b4596;
         /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
         background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#9b4596), to(#6c2787));
         /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
         background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #9b4596, #6c2787);
         /* Firefox 3.6+ */
         background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #9b4596, #6c2787);
         /* IE 10 */
         background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #9b4596, #6c2787);
         /* Opera 11.10+ */
         background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #9b4596, #6c2787);
         }
         #right {
         width: 250px;
         vertical-align: middle;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container">
         <div id="left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
         </div>
         <div id="middle">
            <h3>School of Computing</h3>
         </div>
         <div id="right">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-250-150-1.jpg">
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well to start off you would need a few input fields, for colour, text etc. Then using jQuery you could grab these values, and update a `textarea` with the HTML for example. And also show a visual representation of the changes using HTML.

Comment: Here you go, I just quickly came up with this. [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/94jf2/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only quickly came up with this to show you how it could be done.

### HTML:

```
<div id="makeBanner">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="left">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-250-150-1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="middle">
             <h3>Space for text here</h3>

        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-250-150-1.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>Image change:
<select id="changeimage">
    <option value="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-250-150-1.jpg">Image 1</option>
    <option value="http://www.reflexskis.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/demo-1.png">Image 2</option>
</select>
<button id="click">Get HTML</button>
<div class="getHTML"></div>
```

### CSS:

```
body {
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
img {
    display: block;
}
h3 {
    font-size:200%
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#a9a9a9;
}
#container > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
#left {
    width: 250px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#middle {
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: 960px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    /* fallback */
    background-color: #9b4596;
    /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#9b4596), to(#6c2787));
    /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #9b4596, #6c2787);
    /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #9b4596, #6c2787);
    /* IE 10 */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #9b4596, #6c2787);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #9b4596, #6c2787);
}
#right {
    width: 250px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.getHTML {
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Right! So using jQuery we can change the image on the banner live (this is our banner preview), then we can click get code and grab the HTML from an element and output this as text! Simple, a quick way to make what you want. You just need to create more options to change the parts you want, its then as simple as hitting that "get code" button.

Hope this helps you, feel free to ask questions.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/94jf2/3/)

---

Here is a version with a better layout (look of it etc). The CSS isnt the best but you can fix all that up if you wanted.

[**BETTER VERSION**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/94jf2/5/embedded/result/)

Comment: You could also move `$(".getHTML").text($("#makeBanner").html());` into the `change` function, so you don't need then `get html` button :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses the working demo is really useful. I will implementing this into a CMS, so do I'll want to have the 'Change Image' option on separate page with an option to save, or update changes. Would this be possible?

Also I tried moving the $(".getHTML").text($("#makeBanner").html()); into the change function, but couldn't get this to work. It will be something I've missed I'm sure as I'm not very competent with handling jQuery.

Thanks,

Ross

Comment: @RossP Its completely up to you, both can be done. Also im not sure what your missing because you just move the line to the `.change`. [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/94jf2/6/) So change the image and the code will appear. If you want it there when the user comes on to the page you need to put it in the `doc ready` part so [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/94jf2/7/)

Comment: Ok that's great, I understand the .change function now. I don't however completely understand how to go about adding new images and updating them in a CMS. I appreciate that you've tried to explain it in the previous answer, but as a jQuery noob I'm still a little confused. Can you explain where I would use the 'Code Here' content? Would this be the code that gets dynamically displayed where I want the banner to show? Would I put all of the other code in the CMS? Sorry for getting a bit confused by all of this